# How to replace the argument of a function?

Tags: functions, replacement, rule

For the following expression,

```
b'[x y/z]+z b''[x y/z]
```

I want to replace the argument of b such that the above expression becomes

```
b'[z]+z b''[z]
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Note that if `xy` is intended to be the product of `x` and `y` then it should be entered as either `x y` (implicit product with a space) or as `x*y` (explicit product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general case where you want to replace all the arguments,

```
(b'[x y/z] + z b''[x y/z]) /. Derivative[n_][b_][x_] :> Derivative[n][b][z]
```

> z b''(z)+b'(z)

No matter what was your previous argument, it will be replaced by `z`.

Answer (score 1):

```
b'[xy/z] + z b''[xy/z] /. {xy/z -> z}
```

gives me an output of

```
b'[z]+z b''[z]
```

Is that what you meant?